# oauth Authentication/WebFilter/Bean-loading issues with Spring Boot, Webflux in Kubernetes?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

(Please let me know how to improve the question, or whether I should have tagged it differently, first time writing a question on stackoverflow after hours of being lost.)

I had to remove some of the URLs to get around the spam filter.

I'm probably doing some very basic mistake, but I just don't know where to go from here, so I'm happy for all kinds of tips.

I have a spring-boot webflux project. It's just a REST API that I want to secure with keycloak. Keycloak and the spring-boot service are deployed into the same namespace of a kubernetes cluster. There are more interactions with other services and the kubernetes-api that have worked before adding spring.security.

I've based my implementation on this demo: https://github.com/rbiedrawa/spring-webflux-keycloak-demo and simplified it to be able to test it better.

The setup works locally just fine, but I just can't get it to work in the cluster. I've tried multiple setups: I have tried the setup below first and then tried to implement my own WebFilter to parse the JWT token myself. The WebFilter wouldn't be used either, so I have implemented a WebFilter that should log requests and that also does not work. I have tried changing the security config (like disabling cors, csrf and such). A /health endpoint without authentication worked without issues.

I have two profiles: `prod` and default. I have removed the profile, just to be sure I'm doing something weird. I'm using gradle and have simplified the Dockerfile to the point it builds within the cluster.

The pod is receiving the right image, I can see that from logs (I also know that the beans are created - I just added prints to the constructors).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM gradle:7.6.0-jdk19
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN apt update -y; apt install curl -y
ENTRYPOINT ["gradle", "bootRun"]
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

// ....
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp'
    implementation 'com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:5.14.2'
    implementation 'io.projectreactor.rabbitmq:reactor-rabbitmq:1.5.6'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'io.kubernetes:client-java:17.0.1'
    implementation 'io.kubernetes:client-java-api-fluent:17.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.24.1'
    testImplementation 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.35.0'
}
```

application.yaml:

```
app:
  security:
    clientId: "<client>"

logging.level:
  org.springframework.security: DEBUG
#  ....

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/<realm>"
          #jwk-set-uri: "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/<realm>/.well-known/openid-configuration/"
```

```java
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
                                                     @Qualifier("jwtFilter")WebFilter jwtFilter,
                                                     @Qualifier("keycloakJwtAuthenticationConverter") Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> jwtAuthenticationConverter
    ) {

        http.csrf(csrfSpec -> csrfSpec.disable())
                .authorizeExchange(authorizeExchangeSpec -> authorizeExchangeSpec.anyExchange().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(httpBasicSpec -> httpBasicSpec.disable())
                .logout(logoutSpec -> logoutSpec.disable())
                .formLogin(formLoginSpec -> formLoginSpec.disable())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth -> oauth
                        .jwt(jwtSpec -> jwtSpec.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter)))
                // fourth try:
                //.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION);
        ;
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "keycloakGrantedAuthoritiesConverter")
    Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> keycloakGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(@Value("${app.security.clientId}") String clientId) {
        return new KeycloakGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(clientId);
    }

    @Bean(name = "keycloakJwtAuthenticationConverter")
    Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> keycloakJwtAuthenticationConverter(
          @Qualifier("keycloakGrantedAuthoritiesConverter") Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> converter) {
        return new ReactiveKeycloakJwtAuthenticationConverter(converter);
    }
```

```java
/*
See https://github.com/rbiedrawa/spring-webflux-keycloak-demo
 */
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KeycloakGrantedAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {
    private static final String ROLES = "roles";
    private static final String CLAIM_REALM_ACCESS = "realm_access";
    private static final String RESOURCE_ACCESS = "resource_access";

    private final Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> defaultAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();

    private final String clientId;

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
        List<String> realmRoles = realmRoles(jwt);
        List<String> clientRoles = clientRoles(jwt, clientId);

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Stream.concat(realmRoles.stream(), clientRoles.stream())
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        authorities.addAll(defaultGrantedAuthorities(jwt));

        System.out.println(authorities);

        return authorities;
    }

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> defaultGrantedAuthorities(Jwt jwt) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(defaultAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt))
                .orElse(emptySet());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected List<String> realmRoles(Jwt jwt) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(jwt.getClaimAsMap(CLAIM_REALM_ACCESS))
                .map(realmAccess -> (List<String>) realmAccess.get(ROLES))
                .orElse(emptyList());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected List<String> clientRoles(Jwt jwt, String clientId) {
        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(clientId)) {
            return emptyList();
        }

        return Optional.ofNullable(jwt.getClaimAsMap(RESOURCE_ACCESS))
                .map(resourceAccess -> (Map<String, List<String>>) resourceAccess.get(clientId))
                .map(clientAccess -> clientAccess.get(ROLES))
                .orElse(emptyList());
    }
}
```

```java
/*
See https://github.com/rbiedrawa/spring-webflux-keycloak-demo
 */
public class ReactiveKeycloakJwtAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> {

    private static final String USERNAME_CLAIM = "preferred_username";
    private final Converter<Jwt, Flux<GrantedAuthority>> jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;

    public ReactiveKeycloakJwtAuthenticationConverter(Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter) {
        Assert.notNull(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter, "jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter cannot be null");
        this.jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new ReactiveJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverterAdapter(
            jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken> convert(Jwt jwt) {
        // @formatter:off
        return this.jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt)
                .collectList()
                .map((authorities) -> new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities, extractUsername(jwt)));
        // @formatter:on
    }

    protected String extractUsername(Jwt jwt) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(jwt.getClaimAsString(USERNAME_CLAIM)).orElseGet(jwt::getSubject);
    }

}
```

The keycloak is available in the cluster and I have tried to authenticate from the pod with curl and that worked fine. The token issuer seems to be correct - although I suspect that my issue is not authentication, but spring-boot not loading/using the beans? I have tried simple prints and nothing is executed.

What I'm doing:

- I'm using a port-forward to the kleyclaok via 8081 locally and use insomnia,this is just to show the process:

```
TOKEN=$(curl --request POST \
  --url /keycloak/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  ...)
curl --request GET \
  --url /... \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{...}'
```

The result looks like this:

```
2023-07-09T14:38:54.763+02:00 DEBUG 651138 --- [     parallel-2] a.DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on '<path>' using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedReactiveAuthorizationManager@64a16132
2023-07-09T14:38:54.764+02:00 DEBUG 651138 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthorizationWebFilter       : Authorization successful
2023-07-09T14:38:54.766+02:00  INFO 651138 --- [     parallel-2] d.h.d.o.config.keycloak.JwtFilter        : Authorization payload: Bearerd.h.dafne.orchestrator.config.LogFilter  : REQUEST: <request>
```

- However on the cluster it's a different story:
  I'm using proxy to proxy call the service.

```
curl --request POST \
  --url /keycloak/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  ...
curl --request GET \
  --url /api/v1/namespaces/<ns>/services/<service>:http/proxy/<path> \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '....'
```

Result on the cluster:

```
> Task :bootRun

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.1)

2023-07-09T13:03:01.816Z  INFO 165 --- [           main] d.h.d.o.OrchestratorApplication          : Starting OrchestratorApplication using Java 19.0.2 with PID 165 (/app/build/classes/java/main started by root in /app)
2023-07-09T13:03:01.818Z  INFO 165 --- [           main] d.h.d.o.OrchestratorApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default" # again, simplified version, defualt contains the right paths
2023-07-09T13:03:02.414Z  INFO 165 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-07-09T13:03:02.417Z  INFO 165 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-07-09T13:03:02.463Z  INFO 165 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 28 ms. Found 0 Redis repository interfaces.
Loading LogFilter
Loading JwtFilter!
2023-07-09T13:03:03.416Z  INFO 165 --- [           main] d.h.d.orchestrator.config.RedisConfig    : Connecing to redis on url userstate-db:8082
2023-07-09T13:03:04.263Z  INFO 165 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8080
2023-07-09T13:03:04.273Z  INFO 165 --- [           main] d.h.d.o.OrchestratorApplication          : Started OrchestratorApplication in 2.868 seconds (process running for 3.176)
2023-07-09T13:03:46.204Z DEBUG 165 --- [or-http-epoll-2] .s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter$DefaultRequireCsrfProtectionMatcher@256237f7
2023-07-09T13:03:46.205Z DEBUG 165 --- [or-http-epoll-2] .s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : Did not match
2023-07-09T13:03:46.225Z DEBUG 165 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/logout', method=POST}
2023-07-09T13:03:46.228Z DEBUG 165 --- [     parallel-1] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'GET /service/yml' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
2023-07-09T13:03:46.228Z DEBUG 165 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : No matches found
2023-07-09T13:03:46.231Z DEBUG 165 --- [     parallel-1] a.DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on '<path>' using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedReactiveAuthorizationManager@28fc745d
2023-07-09T13:03:46.234Z DEBUG 165 --- [     parallel-1] ebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext found in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@2f91c766'
2023-07-09T13:03:46.234Z DEBUG 165 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthorizationWebFilter       : Authorization failed: Access Denied
2023-07-09T13:03:46.240Z DEBUG 165 --- [     parallel-1] ebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext found in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@2f91c766'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer does not relate to spring security.

The reason it was not working, is that the `Authentication` header is stripped by `kubectl proxy`. I would argue that having at least some log would have been helpful (I tried to set `debug` for everything, but even with that, I couldn't see an indicator for this). I only noticed it, when I had removed all of spring.security to implement a security check myself - I tried to get the header via `@RequestHeader` annotation. This finally gave me what I need, because only then did spring log that there was no `Authentication` header present.